# Spinner with different row heights

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

Is there a way to create a custom `Spinner` in Android with different drop-down row heights.For example the first and last rows height should be bigger than the middle ones.

EDIT: Tried setting spinner row height at runtime.
The result looks good, but there is a bottom padding when the dropdown is open:

[image: Padding bottom]

I have set the row heights in the getDropDownView() method:

```
@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, null);

        if (position == 0) {
            row.setMinimumHeight(200);
            row.setPadding(row.getPaddingLeft(), 40, row.getPaddingRight(), row.getPaddingBottom());
        } else if (position == getCount() - 1) {
            row.setMinimumHeight(200);
            row.setPadding(row.getPaddingLeft(), row.getPaddingTop(), row.getPaddingRight(), row.getPaddingBottom() + 8);
        }
    }
    return row;
}
```

Comment: Use custom adapter to set on spinner and set the height at runtime .

Comment: This adds a padding to the bottom when the dropdown is open.

Comment: What adds ? Post the code . Till now its just a imaginary spinner .